# How to deserialize BigDecimal by using GWT AutoBean?

Tags: java, json, gwt, autobean

I have json coming from server and representing pojos. When i deserialize to json using AutoBean some works some dont! I figure out that those which cant be deserialize has BigDecimal getters/setters.

**Error:**

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
>       at java_math_BigDecimal_$initFrom__Ljava_math_BigDecimal_2Ljava_lang_String_2

How to handle BigDecimal into GWT while deserializing with AutoBean?

ps:

the nested question is this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15247259/which-interfaces-representations-to-deserialize-from-json-to-autobean/15248423?noredirect=1#15248423)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AutoBean expects `BigDecimal` as strings in the JSON payload.

We discussed it at http://gwt-code-reviews.appspot.com/1601805/
Feel free to file an issue though, the decision was not a "no" but rather a "not now".

Comment: Thank you!! i will do it like u said!